# how to control two scroll bar appear in single screen when loading external php file within the div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to load an external php file within the div. While loading a file I am getting two scroll bar appear in the screen.

[image]

I want to only the outer scroll bar visible. The external php file scroll bar must not be visible. How to control the scroll bar?

```js
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="tab1.php" style="min-width:100%; min-height: 101%;" ></object>';
```

```css
body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }
 .main_content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;

 }
```

```html
<div class="main_content" id="main"></div>
```

The external php file will contain more content, so I need scroll bar functionality. but should not be visible in the main screen.

Comment: There is only 1 scrollbar in your snippet. But overflow hidden on the element that need the scrollbar bar removed will do the trick. Remove the height for the element where you will load the php content .

Comment: @MarkBaijens. Only one scroll appear in the main div, but when loading external php am getting two scroll bar, please refer to the screenshot.
overflow-x:hidden is for bottom scroll hidden

Comment: why you putted **overflow-x: hidden;**

Comment: try first `body{
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
 }`, it will adjust your screen, now go for overflows wherever you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's cause in your snippet you've got

```
min-height:101%;
```

On your object tag?

That will always make it bigger than the block it's in - which will force scrollbars to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

to

```
overflow: hidden;
```

refer:http://jsfiddle.net/eot1me5s/17/

```js
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="tab1.php" style="min-width:100%; min-height: 101%;" ></object>';
```

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .main_content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;

 }
```

```html
<div class="main_content" id="main"></div>
```